# How can I specify the range of an integer in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, integer, check-constraints, mariadb-10.4

I tried to add a column to my table where the integer needs to be in between 01067 and 99998. But The problem is that I don't know how to specify the range of an integer in SQL, so I tried it with the BETWEEN Operator, but I still didn't work. I'm using MariaDB 10.4 and PhpMyAdmin, just for your knowledge.

This is the error: #1064 - you have an error in your SQL syntax

This is my code:
`ALTER TABLE p_infos ADD plz SMALLINT (plz BETWEEN 01067 AND 99998);`

Comment: If you're using MySQL, why also tag MariaDB and Firebird?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry my mistake.

Comment: In any case, you'll want to check the MySQL documentation for the correct syntax for check constraints (you're missing the `CHECK` keyword).

Comment: See [CHECK Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Comment: .. and pay attention, that MySQL version must be 8.0.16 or newer.

Comment: @Akina  in phpMyAdmin, it says I am running MariaDB version 10.4.28, although I started MySQL in XAMPP. Or did I misunderstand something? If this is a dumb question, I'm sorry, but I'm new to SQL.

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL are different products. I've edited your tags and references to MySQL to be more clear that you are using MariaDB.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 and later support `CHECK` constraints. You can use reference documentation here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints or view this tutorial: https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-check-constraint/